# Unable to use FirstOrDefault on SqlParameterCollection

Tags: c#, linq

There is a method that examines an SqlParameterCollection for a ReturnValue parameter and if present checks that value for a constraint violation.

```
      public static void VerifyUniqueness(this ISqlServerProvider provider, 
OperationType operationType, SqlParameterCollection cp)
```

Within this method I thought it was enough to first check:

```
if (cp["@ReturnValue"]==null){return;}
```

but that throws an exception if "@ReturnValue" == null so then I thought I'd use Linq:

```
cp.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ParameterName == "@ReturnValue");
```

but that wont even compile.

> 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection' does not contain a
>   definition for 'FirstOrDefault' and no extension method
>   'FirstOrDefault' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

System.Linq is referenced so not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason you can't use `FirstOrDefault` is that `SqlParameterCollection` does not implement `IEnumerable<SqlParameter>` (on which the LINQ expressions are defined).

The intended method of checking for a parameter is to use [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136446.aspx)

```
if (cp.Contains("@ReturnValue"))
```

If you really want to use LINQ operators, you can use [`Cast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136446.aspx):

```
cp.Cast<SqlParameter>()
  .FirstOrDefault(p => p.ParameterName == "@ReturnValue")
```

Comment: No I dont want to use Linq. I actually keyed for Contains but it was giving me an object reference so I figured it would search by parameter reference. Now Im getting a couple of extra overrides in intellisense including parameter name. Gah, bad day. Thx for the Cast tho, learnt something there.